# How to get ForeignKey value for specific field in Django view

Tags: python, django

I have two models defined in my models.py:

```
class model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'ID: %s, name - %s, description - %s' % (str(self.pk), self.name, self.desc)

class model2(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    repo_id = models.ForeignKey(model1, to_field='id', db_column="repo_id", null=False)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'ID: %s, rpt_repo_id - %s, created_date - %s' % (str(self.pk), str(self.repo_id.pk), self.created_date)
```

I want to query from model2 to fetch name from model1 where id(pk) of model1 is value from rpt_repo_id of model2. Below query doesn't work here:

```
saved_reports = models.model2.objects.all()
```

Although `{{ repo_id.name }}` works fine in html.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use the same technique in your view, as you did in your template:

```
saved_reports = model2.objects.all()
for report in saved_reports:
    print('ID: {} Name: {}'.format(report.repo_id.pk, report.repo_id.name))
```

If you know the id of the model1 object, and want to use that to fetch the model2 object:

```
model2.objects.filter(repo_id__pk=1)
```

Django automatically creates [reverse relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) for foreign keys. This means that if you have a `model1` object, you can get its related `model2` object, even if you only defined the foreign key in the `model2` object:

```
model1.objects.get(pk=1).model2_set.all()  # Fetch me all model2 for this model1
```

Comment: How can I use this way:

`for report in saved_reports:
    for key, value in model_to_dict(report).iteritems():
        if key == 'repo_id':
            print key, value`

How to use `value.name` here?

Comment: My very first example shows you how to do exactly this. The way you have written it in the comment is not how you use the django orm.

Answer (score 0):

change `str(self.repo_id.pk)` to `str(self.repo_id.id)`

Comment: Doesn't work. I queried `saved_reports = models.model2.objects.all()` and then `for r in saved_report: r.name`

Answer (score 0):

There is no field 'name' in model2(), it is in related table model1()

```
saved_reports = model2.objects.all()
for r in saved_reports:
    print r.repo_id.name
```

Comment: How can I use this way: 
`for report in saved_reports: 
    for key, value in model_to_dict(report).iteritems(): 
        if key == 'repo_id': print key, value`
How to use `value.name` here?